# Python autocompletion/syntax check package for Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublime-text

I need some package for Sublime Text for Python.

I need autocompletion, syntax check, check module import error like it in PyCharm.

But I can't find anything useful for Sublime. I tried Anaconda, but it's completely useless and even don't mark any syntax error. Even don't say about module import checking.

Maybe someone know some good plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jedi](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Jedi%20-%20Python%20autocompletion) or to setup whole python project in sublime [here](https://realpython.com/setting-up-sublime-text-3-for-full-stack-python-development/)